# Is Facebooker for Rails still up to date and applicable for developing facebook applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebooker

I'm having some difficulties with following facebook_tutorial on http://apps.facebook.com/facebooker_tutorial/ and
wonder if this plugin is still up to date with the current Facebook API? For example, I'm trying to send notification or post in news feed but get errors like 'Undefined method' however I do everything just like in tutorial.

And what are the differences between Facebooker and Facebooker2? Is facebooker2 written by the same author? I found only simple readme and no tutors at all.

Answer (score 2):

I recently developed a Facebook Rails application using Facebooker (and just blogged about it here: http://www.arctickiwi.com/blog/12-developing-facebook-applications-for-ruby-on-rails )

Haven't used Facebooker2 but I know the developer on Facebooker is still responding to questions on the mailing list.

The Facebooker library is not always 100% up to date with the API unfortunately, the developer mentions you do need to check the Facebook docs first.

HTH

Jonno

Answer (score 1):

Notifications have been removed by Facebook. There's quite a lot of churn in the Facebook API. You'll want to keep up with it.

Facebooker2 is what I plan on maintaining in the future. It is a simplified way of interacting with Facebook. It only supports FBConnect and IFrame canvas apps. It's significantly easier to use and much less invasive.

I do still answer question about Facebooker on the Google Group. I'm happy to take patches and will do my best to help you solve problems.